# How to set tooltips on ListView Subitems in .Net

Tags: vb.net, listview, tooltip

I am trying to set the tool tip text for some of my subitems in my listview control.  I am unable to get the tool tip to show up.

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
Private _timer As Timer
Private Sub Timer()
    If _timer Is Nothing Then
        _timer = New Timer
        _timer.Interval = 500
        AddHandler _timer.Tick, AddressOf TimerTick
        _timer.Start()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TimerTick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    _timer.Enabled = False
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    If Not _timer.Enabled Then
        Dim item = Me.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
        If Not item Is Nothing AndAlso Not item.SubItem Is Nothing Then
            If item.SubItem.Text = "" Then
                Dim tip = New ToolTip
                Dim p = item.SubItem.Bounds
                tip.ToolTipTitle = "Status"
                tip.ShowAlways = True
                tip.Show("FOO", Me, e.X, e.Y, 1000)
                _timer.Enabled = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

    MyBase.OnMouseMove(e)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) (an open source wrapper around .NET WinForms ListView) has builtin support for cell tooltips (and, yes, it does work with VB). You listen for a `CellToolTip` event and you can do things like this (which is admittedly excessive):

[image]

If you don't want to use ObjectListView, you need to subclass ListView, listen for `WM_NOTIFY` messages, and then within those, respond to `TTN_GETDISPINFO` notifications, in a manner similar to this:

```
case TTN_GETDISPINFO:
    ListViewHitTestInfo info = this.HitTest(this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
    if (info.Item != null && info.SubItem != null) {
        // Call some method of your own to get the tooltip you want
        String tip = this.GetCellToolTip(info.Item, info.SubItem); 
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tip)) {
            NativeMethods.TOOLTIPTEXT ttt = (NativeMethods.TOOLTIPTEXT)m.GetLParam(typeof(NativeMethods.TOOLTIPTEXT));
            ttt.lpszText = tip;
            if (this.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes)
                ttt.uFlags |= 4;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(ttt, m.LParam, false);
            return; // do not do normal processing
        }
    }
    break;
```

Obviously, this is C#, not VB, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I would rather not use a control since this is the only thing left I need to do for my listview control.
Is there a tutorial or example on how to "listen for WM_NOTIFY messages" ?  Thanks

Comment: Just download the code for ObjectListView and have a look at WndProc() in ObjectListView.cs.

Comment: I think I got it working except for one line.
Dim ttt As TOOLTIPTEXT = DirectCast(m.GetLParam(GetType(NativeMethods.TOOLTIPTEXT)), NativeMethods.TOOLTIPTEXT)  I did not see TOOLTIPTEXT in the NaticeMethods class.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `MouseMove` event:

```
private void listview1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventargs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = listview1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
    ListViewHitTestInfo info = listview1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    if((item != null) && (info.SubItem != null))
    {
        toolTip1.SetToolTip(listview1, info.SubItem.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        toolTip1.SetToolTip(listview1, "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming .NET 2.0 or later, you can also set [ListView.ShowItemToolTips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.showitemtooltips.aspx) to `true`. If you need to customize the tooltip text for a given item, set [ListViewItem.ToolTipText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.tooltiptext(v=VS.90).aspx) to the string you want displayed.

Answer (score 4):

The original code in the question does not work since it creates a `New ToolTip` inside `OnMouseMove`. I guess that the `ToolTip.Show` method is asynchronous and thus the function exits immediately after invoking it, destroying the temporary `ToolTip`. When `Show` gets to execute, the object does not exist anymore.

The solution would be to create a persistent `ToolTip` object, by:

1. a `ToolTip` control on the form; or
2. a private `ToolTip` class field (disposed in the `Finalize` or `Dispose` method of the class); or
3. a `Static` object inside the function.

Also, there is no need to `GetItemAt()` since `ListViewHitTestInfo` already contains both the item and subitem references.
Improving [Colin](/a/4230751/1019109)'s answer, here is my code:

```
Private Sub ListView_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) _
Handles MyList1.MouseMove
    Static prevMousePos As Point = New Point(-1, -1)

    Dim lv As ListView = TryCast(sender, ListView)
    If lv Is Nothing Then _
        Exit Sub
    If prevMousePos = MousePosition Then _
        Exit Sub  ' to avoid annoying flickering

    With lv.HitTest(lv.PointToClient(MousePosition))
        If .SubItem IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(.SubItem.Text) Then
            'AndAlso .Item.SubItems.IndexOf(.SubItem) = 1
            '...when a specific Column is needed

            Static t As ToolTip = toolTip1  ' using a form's control
            'Static t As New ToolTip()      ' using a private variable
            t.ShowAlways = True
            t.UseFading = True
            ' To display at exact mouse position:
            t.Show(.SubItem.Tag, .Item.ListView, _
                   .Item.ListView.PointToClient(MousePosition), 2000)
            ' To display beneath the list subitem:
            t.Show(.SubItem.Tag, .Item.ListView, _
                   .SubItem.Bounds.Location + New Size(7, .SubItem.Bounds.Height + 1), 2000)
            ' To display beneath mouse cursor, as Windows does:
            ' (size is hardcoded in ugly manner because there is no easy way to find it)
            t.Show(.SubItem.Tag, .Item.ListView, _
                   .Item.ListView.PointToClient(Cursor.Position + New Size(1, 20)), 2000)
        End If
        prevMousePos = MousePosition
    End With        
End Sub
```

I've made the code as general as possible so that the function could be assigned to multiple `ListView`s.

Answer (score 3):

If you set ShowItemTooltips for the ListView control in "details" mode and do nothing else, the ListView control will automatically provide tooltips for items and subitems that exceed their column's widths. This turns out to work even if the FullRowSelect property is set to true. If ToolTipText has been set for a ListViewItem and FullRowSelect is true, then the tooltip will appear for the whole row; that's the case where tooltips won't be displayed for subitems.